# Сортировка List<GameObject>

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно отсортировать List по алфавиту используя gameObject.name?

Comment: `myList = myList.OrderBy(g=>g.Name).ToList();`?

Comment: @tym32167 Это LINQ?

Comment: грубо говоря, да

Comment: @tym32167 ну для скрипта редактора хорошо будет

Comment: я без понятия  :)

Comment: @tym32167 пожалуйста оформите как ответ, я отмечу его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сортировки можно использовать LINQ. В примере ниже я сортирую элементы и создаю новый, уже сортированный список.

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(g=>g.Name).ToList();
```